# Is it possible to conditionally set a field value to no duplicates in MS-Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am building a project to manage conferences. The database is on an SQL Server on an AWS instance and I am using MS Access as the front end.

I have a table for Events and a table for Exhibitors
These Tables have a relationship from Events.ID to Exhibitors.EventsID

One of my fields on the Exhibitors table is BoothNumber int Not Null

I would like to ensure that we cannot assign a booth number twice for the same event but have the ability to reuse the number for other (future) events.

Our booth assignment is generic: 1 -75 and this is repeated for every event.

Is something like this possible?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Pretty simple actually. Use a composite key. But there is so little detail here it is hard to even pretend offering any real advice. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

If your data is on sql server, put a multi-field unique index on the table design using two or more fields. Sql server then takes care of the rest preventing duplicate entries.